# LOOKUP function is not working in progress 4GL

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I tried the below code, which should return 123 in lv_id but returning '123/USER@PROSENJIT'.

```
IF LOOKUP('PF', 'PF/123/USER@PROSENJIT', '/') > 0 THEN
DO:    
     ASSIGN        
         lv_id = ENTRY(2,'PF/123/USER@PROSENJIT','/':U)

END.
```

Can anyone please let me what is the wrong here.

Comment: what version of Progress are you using? I just tried this on 10.2B and I get 123

Comment: How to check the progress version, because in some environment I am also getting 123 but in some other environment I am getting '123/USER@PROSENJIT'.

Comment: Are you using Translation Manager? In your `IF` statement you have '/' but your `ASSIGN` has '/':U. It might be that the slash in the `IF` is being translated but the slash in the `ASSIGN` is not. Either add `:U` to the other slash or remove it from the first.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it worked:

```
if LOOKUP('PF', 'PF/123/USER@PROSENJIT', '/') > 0 then
    message ENTRY(2,'PF/123/USER@PROSENJIT','/':U).
```

I'm thinking there's something else going on that's causing your difficulty.